# Zoom related to object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to zoom my player, my player is a ball and it is attached to the camera, basicly i already implemented the zoom code, but somehow it is not zooming the ball correctly when i zoom in the game the ball dissapears, i want to zoom the object and not the camera itself, how can i do that?

**this is whast i tried**

```
void LateUpdate () 
{   
    if(Time.timeScale != 0){
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X)){
            isZoomed = true;
        }else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C)){
            isZoomed = false;
        }

        if(isZoomed == true){
            camera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(camera.fieldOfView,zoom,Time.deltaTime*smooth);
        }
        else{
            camera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(camera.fieldOfView,normal,Time.deltaTime*smooth);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Vector3 moveDirection = Camera.main.transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.forward);
Camera.main.transform.Translate (moveDirection * zoomSpeed * moveDirection);
```

Could be a possible solution. What it does is moving the camera closer to the player. But then you should "unattach" the camera from the player. If you want to move away from the player AKA Zoom out, you can do -moveDirection instead.

Comment: actually solved that with the same code, 2 min before you answer, it is the right answer and thanks :D